# Couchapp && Evently && Mustache: How would I output subarrays?

Tags: mustache, couchapp

I am working on a demo couchapp to output some contact data to a html-container. Right now, I am doing this by generating the html and appending it via javascript.

In CouchDB I could (I would really like) to be using mustache for generating this more automatically, especially for the later editing this data and storing it to the db again...

The JSON structure for now looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "478d86edbbd94bbe627f3ebda300dfb1",
   "_rev": "1-b6b1582f41f38c7a1d3ce43514e97371",
   "accounts": [],
   "activities": [],
   "addresses": [
      {
         "formatted": "B 31\nHeilbronn   74081",
         "streetAddress": "B 31\nHeilbronn   74081",
         "type": "Privat",
         "home": false,
         "primary": false,
         "work": false
      },
      {
         "formatted": "Strasse \nHeilbronn   74081",
         "streetAddress": "Strasse\nHeilbronn   74081",
         "type": "Work",
         "home": false,
         "primary": false,
         "work": false
      }
   ],
   "books": [],
   "cars": [],
   "contactID": 46,
   "date_created": "2011-02-07T19:42:07.813+01:00",
   "date_modified": "2011-02-07T19:42:07.813+01:00",
   "displayName": "Adac Adac",
   "emails": [],
   "foods": [],
   "heroes": []
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I adress to the sub objects, e.g. for "addresses" in mustache? Like this?

   {{#addresses}}

   formatted: {{formatted}}
         streetAddress: {{streetAddress}}
       ...

   {{/addresses}}
2. Would this be a good and reusable approach to also edit this data? How would this be done in CouchApps?

Comment: Can you explain it better? Point 1 is true. Point 2 is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question 1, you may also use partials:

```
{{#addresses}}
    {{>address}}
{{/addresses}}
```

where address will be a html containing the same what you've put in your example, and assigned in your evently statements:

```
partials: [ /* ... */ ],
```